# While uploading image using php function move_uploaded_file() its working locally bt have error "open_basedir restriction in effect."

Tags: php

I have write this php code for uploading image from any remote computer to server upload dir

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000))
{
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"upload/".$filename);
} else {
    echo "invalid file";exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change your uploads folder to:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./upload/".$filename);
```

Comment: Its not working still same error occur "'/upload/abc.JPG' is not within the allowed path"